# Is it possible to use css-file with NgDirective

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have an `NgComponent` and an `NgDirective`, which I want to use with component. My directive  (drop-image) adds a dropping zone functionality for component's div. I also want to add a visual indication of the zone (red border).

I know I can use `element.style.border = "2px solid red"` within the functions in directive, but adding and removing the style like this doesn't feel right (for example if the element already have border-style, it can cause trouble).

Another way is to add class-selector (`.drop-image`) to the component's css-file and then toggle the class in the directive. This method can be found in my examples. The problem here is that I must add the style with the class-selector to component's file and therefore the directive is not "independed".

Is there a way to define a css-style with a class-selector within the NgDirective?

comp.html

```dart
<div drop-image="cmp.user.image">
</div>
```

comp.css

```dart
.drop-image {
  border: solid 2px red;
}
```

drop-image.dart (NgDirective-file)

```dart
void onDragOver(){
  element.classes.add("drop-image");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, but you can for example use `ng-class` to add/remove a CSS class and add some CSS to your page CSS specific to that class.
NgComponent can reference a CSS because the ShadowDOM prevents that the page CSS is applied to its content.

Comment: I couldn't find an easy way to use `ng-class`with directive. I added a new answer, where is a couple of examples of different solutions.

Comment: Just started to read and want to inform you that `applyAuthorStyles` is deprecated and will be removed soon but I heard recently that porting NgTransclude to AngularDart is making good progress.

Comment: If you can't use ng-class you can just inject `Element` to your directive and set the class directly `element.classes.add('someclass');`

Comment: Good to know about `applyAuthorStyles` deprecation, thank you. I'm already using element injection in my examples :)

Comment: I saw it just after I added my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Gunter's answer inspired me to test this a bit more. Here is a few examples how to use `class` or `style` with `NgDirective` and `NgComponent`.

If you use `applyAuthorStyles: true` with a component, then the best place to put your directive related class is a top level css-file (as in my example). This way there is only one place to put your directive related css definitions. If you don't use `applyAuthorStyles`, then you have to put css-code to each component's css-file.

The use of `element.style.border = "2px solid yellow";` works also fine ie. when you remove style by setting the `element.style.border = "";`, previously defined styles are applied again automatically.

I couldn't find an easy way to use `ng-class` (or any other ng-something) with directive. `MyComp2` uses `ng-class` with `my-directive3`, but it feels a bit hacky. Maybe with the `Scope` there is a better way to assign value to ng-class from directive.

EDIT: Gunter pointed out that `applyAuthorStyles` is or will be deprecated.

my_comp.css:

```dart
div {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

ok_dir_css.css:

```dart
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
.test {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

ok_dir_css.html:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OK dir css</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ok_dir_css.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div my-directive1><p>Directive1 with css class</p></div>
    <div my-directive2><p>Directive2 with inline style</p></div>
    <my-comp1></my-comp1>
    <my-comp2></my-comp2>

    <script type="application/dart" src="ok_dir_css.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

ok_dir_css.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgDirective(
    selector: '[my-directive1]'
)
class MyDirective1 {
  Element element;

  MyDirective1(this.element) {
    element
      ..onMouseOver.listen(mouseOver)
      ..onMouseLeave.listen(mouseLeave);
  }

  void mouseOver(MouseEvent event){
    element.classes.add("test");
  }

  void mouseLeave(MouseEvent event){
    element.classes.remove("test");
  }
}

@NgDirective(
    selector: '[my-directive2]'
)
class MyDirective2 {
  Element element;

  MyDirective2(this.element) {
    element
        ..onMouseOver.listen(mouseOver)
        ..onMouseLeave.listen(mouseLeave);
  }

  void mouseOver(MouseEvent event){
    element.style.border = "2px solid yellow";
  }

  void mouseLeave(MouseEvent event){
    element.style.border = "";
  }
}

@NgDirective(
    selector: '[my-directive3]'
)
class MyDirective3 {
  @NgTwoWay('my-directive3')
  String strClass;

  Element element;

  MyDirective3(this.element, Scope scope) {
    element
        ..onMouseOver.listen(mouseOver)
        ..onMouseLeave.listen(mouseLeave);
  }

  void mouseOver(MouseEvent event){
    strClass = "test";
  }

  void mouseLeave(MouseEvent event){
    strClass = null;
  }
}

@NgComponent(
 selector: 'my-comp1',
 template: r'<div my-directive1><p>my-comp1 with Directive1</p></div><div my-directive2><p>my-comp1 with Directive2</p></div>',
 cssUrl: 'my_comp.css', 
 applyAuthorStyles: true,
 publishAs: 'cmp'
)
class MyComp1 {
}

@NgComponent(
    selector: 'my-comp2',
    template: r'<div my-directive3="cmp.classStr" ng-class="cmp.classStr" ng-mouseover="cmp.over()"><p>my-comp2 with ng-class and Directive3</p></div>',
    cssUrl: 'my_comp.css', 
    applyAuthorStyles: true,
    publishAs: 'cmp'
)
class MyComp2 {
  String classStr;

  void over(){
    print("over");
  }
}



class MyAppModule extends Module {
  MyAppModule() {
    type(MyDirective1);
    type(MyDirective2);
    type(MyDirective3);
    type(MyComp1);
    type(MyComp2);
  }
}

void main() {
  ngBootstrap(module: new MyAppModule());
}
```